# Convert string to System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons

Tags: c#, winforms

I wanted to make a function that shows MessageBox with buttons which user chose in ComboBox, but i can't convert string to System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons. I tried this:

```cs
MessageBoxButtons buttons = comboBox1.Text;
```

and this:

```cs
MessageBoxButtons buttons = comboBox1.Text as MessageBoxButtons;
```

but it shows that cannot convert string to System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.
`Parse` function also doesn't work because MessageBoxButtons has no such option
Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=net-6.0

Comment: If you actually added MessageBoxButtons enum values to the ComboBox (and didn't allow arbitrary text entry), you should be able to use ```comboBox1.SelectedItem```